# Gamma Function in Python

Tags: python, gamma-function

I'm fairly new to Python but would like to use Euler's Gamma Function in a function I am writing. I'd prefer not to write it as an integral and was wondering if there's something I can import that easily defines the gamma function.

Thanks

Comment: If you want an arbitrary precision gamma function, take a look at [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/gamma.html).

Comment: Looks like its in the standard library. `from math import gamma; gamma(10);`

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Sure (if you have Python 2.7 or later). But unlike the mpmath version it doesn't handle complex numbers (and there's no gamma in cmath) and of course it's not arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. In the module `math` there are special functions coded such as the Gamma function.

Look at [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#special-functions)

Comment: For Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gamma

Answer (score 9):

I'd use `scipy.special.gamma()`.

Comment: Important note: `scipy.special.gamma()` takes arbitrary np.arrays as input. `math.gamma()` requires float or single-element numpy arrays, which a crippling limitation in many use cases.

Comment: The function `scipy.special.gamma` allows complex numbers, even though `math.gamma` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way:

```
from mpmath import gamma
print(float(gamma(0.5)))
```

> `1.772453850905516`

Answer (score -2):

If you want to go deep with Python and other methods I'll recommend that you look at numpy and scipy libraries.

A gamma function can be as easy as

```
from scipy.stats import gamma
a = 1.99323054838
rv = gamma(a)
```

That's it, check https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gamma.html#scipy.stats.gamma for more info and https://www.scipy.org/ if you want to know more about scientific computing with python.

Comment: That's a different gamma to Euler's gamma.